# Merging Kendo ListView with Fancybox problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox-2, kendo-listview

I'm stuck on this since a week! Any help would be greatly appreciated.!
What I have is some JSON data which now I want to display as thumbnails using Kendo ListView. Also, when we click on the thumbnail image, I want the fancybox to open the dark screen and allow me to view the items. 
With what I've done so far, the kendo ListView manages to show the thumbnails fine, but when I click on the thumbnail image, it redirects me to the whole image and doesn't open the fancybox popup.
My guess is that the two things are intefering because of which Fancybox is probably not able to do stuff.
The page is here: http://butterflydiamonds.com/blank.php

Just click on Tile View once the data has loaded to see what I'm talking about.
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The code for those who don't want to click the link:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<title>Diamond Database</title>
<link href="style/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- Common Kendo UI Web CSS -->
<link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Default Kendo UI Web theme CSS -->
<link href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- jQuery JavaScript -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Kendo UI Web combined JavaScript -->
<script src="js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/css/media-queries.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/type/qlassik.css" media="all" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="style/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="style/js/ddsmoothmenu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="style/js/selectnav.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="style/js/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="style/js/jquery.slickforms.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/forms.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jsonconvert.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="style/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/js/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.2" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="style/js/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.2"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/js/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.2" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="style/js/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="style/js/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.0"></script>
<link href="style/css/classic-081711.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script>
$.noConflict();
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
</head>
<body id="page">
    <!-- Begin Wrapper -->
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Begin Main -->
        <div id="main">
            <div class="container box">
                <div id="container"></div>
                <p id="new"></p>
        <p id="test"></p>
        <!-- Begin Toggle -->

            <h4 class="title">Search Options</h4>

              <div>

             <div style="float: right"> 
                <div style="float: left"><ul class="filter">
        <li><a class="active button dark" id="gridfilter"  onclick="dogridstuff()" data-filter="*">Grid View</a></li>
        <li><a  class="dark button" id="tilefilter" onclick="dotilestuff()" data-filter=".bw">Tile View</a></li>
      </ul></div>
            </div>
              </div>

          <!-- End Toggle --> 

    <div id="database">
        <div id="items" style="display:none">
        <div id="listView" style="margin-left: 50px"></div>
        <div id="pager" class="k-pager-wrap"> </div>
    </div>
    <div id="grid"></div>
    </div>
    <p><b>Note:The column pair id represents respective pairs and prices may vary as per selection, if any.</b></p>

    <br>
    <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template2">

                         <div class="item">
          <div class="thumb">
            <a href= "style/images/art/blue2.png" class="hover fancybox-media" title= #= PID # ><span class="overlay zoom"></span><img src= #= PHOTO #  style="display: inline" onerror="this.src='style/images/imgnotavailable.jpg'" width='280px'></a>
          </div>
          <div class="details">
            <h4 class="entry-title"> #= PID # </a></h4>
          </div>
        </div>
            </script>
           <script>
        var data=[];
        var dataforgrid=[];
        var data2=[];
        var i=1;
        var prev="";
        var text="";
        var source;
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2565723/thedata.js?callback=callback&_=1402638666911',
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    jsonp: 'callback'
                });
            })
        function initSource()
        {

            for(var i=0;i<dataforgrid.length;++i)
            {
                dataforgrid[i].CTS=dataforgrid[i].CTS.toFixed(2);
            }
        source=new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data:dataforgrid,
                 // {transport:{
                    // read: {
                        // url:"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2565723/thedata.js",
                        // dataType:"jsonp",
                        // jsonpCallback: 'callback'
                    // }}               


                schema: {
                                model: {
                                    fields: {
                                        PID: { type: "string",editable: false},
                                        SELECT: {type:"boolean",editable: false},
                                        SPRICE: { type: "number",editable: false },
                                        SHAPE: { type: "string",editable: false },
                                        PCS: { type: "number",editable: false },
                                        COLID: {editable: false},
                                        CTS: {editable: false},
                                        PHOTO: {editable: false},
                                        DESCRIPTION: {editable: false},
                                        CLARITY: {editable: false},
                                        POLISH: {editable: false},
                                        SYMMETRY: {editable: false},
                                        L: {editable: false},
                                        W: {editable: false},
                                        TD: {editable: false},
                                        D: {editable: false},
                                        FLU: {editable: false},
                                    }
                                }
                           },
                autoSync: true,
                sort:
                [{field:"COLID",dir:"asc"},
                {field:"DESCRIPTION",dir:"asc"},
                {field:"CTS",dir:"asc"}
                ],
                pageSize: 20
            }); 
                initGrid();

           }
           function dogridstuff()
           {
            $("#tilefilter").removeClass("active");
            $("#gridfilter").addClass("active");
            $("#grid").show();
            document.getElementById("items").style.display='none';
           }
           function dotilestuff()
           {
            $("#tilefilter").addClass("active");
            $("#gridfilter").removeClass("active");
            prepareDataForTile();
            initTile();
            $("#grid").hide();
            document.getElementById("items").style.display='block';
           }
           function initTile()
           {
            updateSource();
            $("#pager").kendoPager({
                dataSource: source,
                pageSizes: [9,18,27,54],
                buttonCount: 5
            });

            $("#listView").kendoListView({
                dataSource: source,
                selectable: false,
                template: kendo.template($("#template2").html())
            });
           }
           function prepareDataForTile()
           {
                for(var i=0;i<dataforgrid.length;++i)
                {
                    if(dataforgrid[i].PHOTO=="")
                    dataforgrid.splice(i--,1);
                }
           }
        function callback(datafromfile)
        {
            dataforgrid=datafromfile;
            data=datafromfile;
            for(var i=0;i<dataforgrid.length;++i)
            {
                dataforgrid[i].SELECT=false;
                data[i].SELECT=false;
            }
            data[0].SELECT=true;
            initSource();
        }
        function updateSource()
        {
            source=new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data:dataforgrid,
                schema: {
                                model: {
                                    fields: {
                                        PID: { type: "string",editable: false},
                                        SELECT: {type: "boolean",editable: true},
                                        SPRICE: { type: "number",editable: false },
                                        SHAPE: { type: "string",editable: false },
                                        PCS: { type: "number",editable: false },
                                        COLID: {editable: false},
                                        CTS: {editable: false},
                                        PHOTO: {editable: false},
                                        DESCRIPTION: {editable: false},
                                        CLARITY: {editable: false},
                                        POLISH: {editable: false},
                                        SYMMETRY: {editable: false},
                                        L: {editable: false},
                                        W: {editable: false},
                                        TD: {editable: false},
                                        D: {editable: false},
                                        FLU: {editable: false},
                                    }
                                }
                           },
                autoSync: true,
                sort:
                [{field:"COLID",dir:"asc"},
                {field:"DESCRIPTION",dir:"asc"},
                {field:"CTS",dir:"asc"}
                ],
                pageSize: 20
            });
            //functions for Kendogrid, filtering search, etc. not relevant to question           
        </script>

        </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Main -->
    </div>
    <!-- End Wrapper -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="style/js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't ask people to click on unknown links but rather include your relevant (html/jQuery) code in your question

Comment: If that is your exact code, then you are missing a closing bracket `};` so my guess is that triggers a js error that prevents fancybox from working. I would advise you to use a jslint tool to debug your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the problem. It was conflicting jQuery calls. Solved using jQuery.fancybox() instead of $.fancybox().